# Does Hazelcast store metadata information?

Tags: hazelcast

As part of storing data. Does hazelcast stores metadata information like RIAK?.
If so, whether we can store custom metadata information?.

Thanks in advance

Dinesh

Answer (score 2):

What kind of metadata stores riak and what kind of data do you want to store?

We store some internal metadata like last access timestamp or hits and similar but this probably not what you're asking for. We also do not have user custom metadata depending on what you expect to store. Custom metadata can for sure be stored in another map using the same key.

Comment: Thanks noctarius. RIAK allows to store custom information (usermetadata)at each bucket/key level.Some our business cases needs this for searching a particular pattern of data.By default it stores **last updated since, read_quarom, vclock etc..**

Comment: we have some of those metadata too but they aren't accessible without going to internal api. for user metadata you should use another map or something as states before