# Hazelcast map atkes almost double memory even after disabling backup

Tags: hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast as a distributed key-value store. I have 650Million keys. Each entry in Hazelcast cost 204 bytes. So, it was supposed to consume only ~130GB memory. But, it is taking almost twice the memory it is supposed to take although we disabled the backup.

The java file (which is starting the server as well as creating the map) looks like following:

```
public class Driver {
    public static IMap<String, byte[]> createMap(String mapName, HazelcastInstance hzc){
        IMap <String, byte[]> map = hzc.getMap(mapName);
        return map;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Config config = new XmlConfigBuilder(args[0]).build();
            HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
            IMap<String, byte[]> map = createMap("DBG", hz);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {s
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

In Hazelcast.xml we made the following change (as you can see in the java file attached our map-name is DBG):

```
<map name="DBG">
    <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    <backup-count>0</backup-count>
    <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <min-eviction-check-millis>100</min-eviction-check-millis>
    <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
</map>
```

Comment: How many nodes do you start up?

Comment: I started 128 nodes.
Today I checked the memory usage of Hazelcast. Even if I store just key-value pair  <"1", "1">  it is taking 168bytes. Does it make sense? Am I missing something? (I checked the usage like this: System.out.println(map.getEntryView("1").getCost());)

Comment: Sure it does make sense. We have to store additional type information, we serialize the strings as utf8, there are statistics like hits, misses, lastaccess, etc. Here is a thread about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809427/does-hazelcast-store-metadata-information/28809891

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to NOT to store some of the metadata. As for example I don't need hits, miss or last-access-time. Is it possible to disable these by changing the xml/configuration-parameters?

Comment: @user3606212, I think there are two types of statistics available with Hz maps. Entry statistics and map statistics. As of Hz 3.*.* we are able to disable map statistics from config, statistics-enabled = false. However, not sure if we can disable entry statistics.